# Vue3 and Vuetify: @update:options not triggering with :search for v-data-table

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I am using v-data-table to retrieve information but when I type in the v-text-field to update the search string it does not trigger the @update:options event.

```
        <v-data-table-server 
          v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
          :headers="headers" 
          :items="clients" 
          :items-length="totalItems"
          :search="search"
          :loading="loading"
          class="elevation-1"
          @update:options="loadItems"
          @click:row="showModal">
            <template v-slot:top>
              <v-text-field
              v-model="search"
              append-icon="mdi-magnify"
              label="Client Search"
              single-line
              hide-details
              ></v-text-field>
            </template>
        </v-data-table-server>
```

This is what I have written and the values are changed by the text field but it does not trigger the event like expected.